# Unable to publish spotbugs in jenkins using pipeline script

Tags: groovy, build, jenkins-pipeline, findbugs, spotbugs

I am running spotbugs through an Ant task but I am unable to publish the results to jenkins. I am getting the below error

```
[FindBugs] No valid reference build found that meets the criteria (NO_JOB_FAILURE - SUCCESSFUL_QUALITY_GATE)
[FindBugs] All reported issues will be considered outstanding
```

This is the jenkins script I am using

```
stage('Publish Spotbugs')
            {
                def findbugs = scanForIssues tool: [$class: 'FindBugs'], pattern: '**/findbugsXml.xml'
                publishIssues issues:[findbugs]
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you are using Spotbugs. In your pipeline you are using the Findbugs Publisher. Spotbugs is a Findbugs fork. If you really are using Spotbugs I recomend to use the Spotbugs Publisher instead.

```
stage('Publish Spotbugs')
{
  def spotbugs = scanForIssues tool: spotBugs(pattern: '**/target/findbugsXml.xml')
  publishIssues issues: [spotbugs]
}
```

The report-XML filename depends on your configuration. It could also be `spotbugsXml.xml`. Have you verified your target folder after running the ant task?

For more information about the pipeline configuration of the Warnings Next Generation Plugin see the [documentation on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#pipeline-configuration) or the [jenkins user documtation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/).

Comment: Hi Matthias - Thanks for your response. Its working fine now. But I could able to run spot bugs and publish it only against one Jar at a time. Is there any way to publish spot bugs against multiple jars

Comment: There is a way. After all build steps have succeeded there should be a `findbugsXml.xml` file in each target folder. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes. I am getting findbugs.xml in all the folders but could only publish one xml file in jenkins.How to publish all xml files???

Comment: I think the pattern needs to be more generally. Please try `**/findbugsXml.xml`

Comment: Yeah I am using the same pattern. But it only publishes one xml

Comment: Can you provide the output of job console log? Starting with ``[SpotBugs] Searching for all files in 'workspace/JOB_NAME' that match the pattern '**/spotbugsXml.xml'``

Comment: Finally its considering only one xml... [FindBugs] Successfully parsed file C:\Jenkins\jobs\StrategicModeling\branches\users-nagesw.c96v3q.k-b-spotbugs\workspace\HSFRoot\Java\HSFCommon\findbugsXml.xml
[FindBugs] -> found 88 issues (skipped 0 duplicates)
[FindBugs] Successfully parsed file C:\Jenkins\jobs\StrategicModeling\branches\users-nagesw.c96v3q.k-b-spotbugs\workspace\HSFRoot\Java\findbugsXml.xml
[FindBugs] -> found 1276 issues (skipped 88 duplicates)

Comment: I disagree. There are two different XML files that he considered (HSFCommon\findbugsXml.xml and HSFRoot\Java\findbugsXml.xml). The issues of both files should result aggregated in the published results.

Comment: Its considering the most recent results and skipping the old ones with message :found 1276 issues (skipped 88 duplicates)

Comment: honestly with the input i have, i think it is working as designed. Would you mind using spotbugs instead of findbugs? [Findbugs](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs) really is not maintained anymore since two years. That means no bugs are fixed.

Comment: Sure. I will try and let you know

Comment: Hi- I have used spotubgs but still facing the same issue. :(. Kindly help me to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198556/discussion-between-jon-and-matthias).